# prepareForSegue works for modal segue but not push segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

The issue that I am having is that when I try to pass data to the `destinationViewController` with a push segue, it looks as if its not getting passed. When I change the segue to a modal segue everything works perfectly.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToPlayCapturedMedia" sender:self];

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"segueToPlayCapturedMedia"]) {
        MediaPlayerViewController* mediaPlayerVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        mediaPlayerVC.fileURL = self.currentMediaFileURL;

        NSLog(@"on segue the recieved media file is  %@", mediaPlayerVC.fileURL);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I am able to `NSLog` the `mediaPlayerVC.fileURL` but when I try Logging the `fileURL` in `viewDidLoad` of the `MediaPlayerViewController`, the value is `nil`.

It almost seems to me that the instance of `MediaPlayerViewController` being displayed is different than the one created during the segue.

Comment: Did you try logging in the `viewWillAppear:` method?

Comment: Did you debug the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the definition of your property fileURL in mediaPlayerVC.h
It should be something like :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Type-mayBe-NSURL *fileURL;
```

**strong** is really important !